# How to display only selected data in combo box at run time from database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, combobox

I am new to .Net and I am working on one task. Below is my scenario.

I have 2 tables:

- Table 1: Students

  ```
  StudentID   StudentDetail
      1         StudentName
      2        StudentGrade
  ```
- Table 2: Student_data

  ```
  StudentDetail  StudentRecords
   StudentName   John (Default)
   StudentName      Jacob
   StudentName      Smith
   StudentGrade            A    (default)
   StudentGrade            B
   StudentGrade            C
  ```

**Question**: When window form loads (run time) I need to display StudentRecords in combo box with `StudentName = "John"` and `StudentGrade = "A"` as default followed by other values.

`StudentName` and `StudentRecords` are in `Label`s and values are in a `ComboBox`.

I am using VB.Net and VS 2010 with SQL 2008r2.

I would appreciate any step by step help. Apologies If my request is simple.

Comment: @ChrisF It's difficult to imagine how to deal with that :P

Comment: Do you really have those tables in your database or neither?

Comment: I don't understand your data model. There should be one Table with the fields (StudentID, Name, Grade). why two tables?

Comment: I agree with @OlivierJacot-Descombes, your data model is highly confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. (In form design you have label named 'student name' and combo box with 3 names in it.) when you load form Names should display in combo box with default name.) Hope it might help?

Comment: I agree @OlivierJacot-Descombes, but This is task requirement to have 2 tables. Am I missing something which is not clear to you? Thanks,

Comment: I understand that you want to have the grades in a lookup table, but the student names? How could such a table possibly contain all the possible student names? You could have one Student table with the fields (StudentID, Name, GradeID) and a Grade table with the fields (GradeID, GradeLetter, OtherValueRelatedToGrade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should think to start rethinking your data model. Some like this will be enough:

[image: simple data model]

This way you can have:

- Student

  ```
  id       name       [   oGrade    ]
  ```

  ---

  ```
   1       John       [      1      ]
   2       Paco       [      1      ]
   3       Jacinto    [      2      ]
  ```
- Grade

  ```
  id       grade      [   aoStudent    ]
  ```

  ---

  ```
   1         A        [   John, Paco   ]
   2         B        [   Jacinto      ]
   3         C        [   Nothing      ]
  ```

Anyway, this way you only can have a Grade per Student. So, it's not much helpful. Something more complex is needed if you want to keep a track of the students grades for each subject and several tests per subject. Here you have another model a little more complex having that into account:

[image: more complex model]

Again, you need to stop and think about your problem.

Comment: ..Thanks for your help. I am able to get expected results with above mentioned data model. I made changes to my data model.